# How to mock __init__ method

Tags: python, boto3

I want to mock below code, can you suggest any way to achieve this?

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = boto3.resource(DYNAMODB)
        self.table = self.client.Table(TABLE_NAME)
```

Below is the code I wrote but I am not sure if it's correct or not.

```
@mock.patch.object(ClassName, '__init__', return_value=None)
@mock.patch.object(boto3, "client")
@mock.patch.object(boto3, "table", return_value=create_response)
```

Comment: _Don't_ mock `__init__`. Don't mock parts of the things you're supposed to be testing. I guess you're doing that to reduce the coupling of your code to the AWS dependencies to make your code easier to test, in which case: _invert_ the dependency, make the `client` a _parameter_ that's passed in on initialisation.

Comment: When writing tests, we often find the need to rewrite the application code in order to make it *easier to be tested*. 95% of the time this translates into cleaner application code, too. In your case, I would rewrite the application code to initialize `self.client` and `self.table` as `None`, and create a method `connect()` that actually connects your class to the database. No need to mock anything then - simply instantiate your class and don't call the `connect()` method afterwards.

Comment: @jfaccioni the downside of that is you have something that's not actually ready to use when initialised, you're splitting one semantic job across two methods.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for your response, I am new to python i didn't get completely your comment actually. can you please brief me I trying to understanding it with other language experiences but not catching exactly.

Comment: If my comment didn't make sense to you, read up on the "dependency inversion principle".

Comment: hey @jonrsharpe that's really good, I will try decoupling, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend either passing the client object or make a method that connects.
If this is not possible and you still want to test the code then you should download the moto library. This contains useful functions for mocking aws resources here is the link to its page at pypi https://pypi.org/project/moto/
this is the link to its documentation page http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/getting_started.html
this is how you would use it

```
from moto import mock_dynamodb2
import unittest
class some_test_class(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock_dynamodb2
    def test_some_test_that_uses_dynamodb(self):
        dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb',region_name='us-east-1')
        dynamo.create_table(
            AttributeDefinitions = [
                {
                    'AttributeName':'key_for_table',
                    'AttributeType':'S'
                }
            ],
            TableName='table_name',
            KeySchema = [{
               'AttributeName':'key_for_table',
               'KeyType':'HASH'
            }],
            ProvisionedThroughput = 
                {'ReadCapacityUnits':100,
                'WriteCapacityUnits':100}
            }
```

After this you can use a function or class that uses dynamodb as long as it is called from within this test and as long as it did not make a connection before the class mocked the service.It will mock out the service so that it uses this in memory table instead.